# Elkies' family of elliptic curves of rank 19

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

There is a widely cited fact that Elkies had found that infinitely many curves of rank 19 in 2006, in "Z^28 in E(Q), etc. Email to the number theory mailing list
at NMBRTHRY@LISTSERV.NODAK.EDU". I was unable to find the actual equation for this family of elliptic curves. Was this email preserved somewhere, or is it lost to history?

Comment: Noam Elkies is still active, you could email..., or even Andrej Dujella, who maintains the webpage with the records https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/tors/generic.html. But as a tiny piece of evidence it's not lost, page 10 of Elkies' _[Three lectures on elliptic surfaces and curves of high rank](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.2908)_ seems to discuss the matter

Comment: BTW, the cited email itself is https://listserv.nodak.edu/cgi-bin/wa.exe?A2=NMBRTHRY;99f4e7cd.0605&FT=&P=&H=&S= and Elkies promises to post the equations for the infinite family at a future date, but I cannot find them among the 2006 or 2007 postings.

Comment: Ideally this data would be put into https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/?rank=19 when it becomes available!

Comment: Btw, what Elkies in his email calls C123 (a composite co-factor of the discriminant) has been factored since then: http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000001289397697